# How to find text within [] in Sed?

Tags: regex, sed

This is similar to a question that has already been asked.  However, I am looking for a Sed specific answer.  I have text similar to the following:

Some sample text [with some extra text].foo

I need to grab just the text inside the brackets.  My attempts thus far have been futile.  I can parse the line with other tools but I can't seem to get Sed to parse it correctly.

Comment: If you have multiple bracketed expressions per line, and bracketed expressions that extend across several lines, then it seems that you could do this much easier with a character by character parser. This is going to be a fairly miserable exercise with sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ echo Some sample text [with some extra text].foo | sed -e 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'
with some extra text

$ echo Some sample text [with some extra text].foo | sed -e 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/Your text was: "\1", okay?/g'
Your text was: "with some extra text", okay?
```

Comment: The key point in this answer is the use of single quotes around the sed expression - something that should have been stated in the answer.  It is crucial; otherwise, the shell removes the backslashes and sed 'sees' expressions without them, and doesn't interpret it the way you'd like it to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example the replaces the text inside brackets:

```
$ echo 'Some sample text [with some extra text].foo' | sed -e 's/\[\(with some extra text\)\]/<\1>/g'
Some sample text <with some extra text>.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Some [sample inside] text [with some extra text].foo" | sed -n '/\[/{ s/\]/\n/g; s/.[^\n]*\[/:/g;s/\..*//;p}'
:sample inside:with some extra text
```