# SED to keep text between tags over multiple lines

Tags: regex, sed

I am very new to sed and so even with looking at examples I am totally at a loss as how to go about writing the correct code for my need ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905180/how-to-find-text-within-in-sed) is close but it seems not for multi-line replacement.

Here is my input.txt

> This is a test of splitting...
>
> |firstword|secondwordthirdword
>   fourthwordfifthwordsixthword
>
> This is a test of splitting...
>
> firstword|secondword|thirdword
>   fourthwordfifthwordsixthword
>
> This is a test of splitting...
>
> firstwordsecondword|thirdword|
>   fourthwordfifthwordsixthword
>
> This is a test of splitting...
>
> firstwordsecondwordthirdword
>   |fourthword|fifthwordsixthword
>
> This is a test of splitting...
>
> firstwordsecondwordthirdword
>   fourthword|fifthword|sixthword
>
> This is a test of splitting...
>
> firstwordsecondwordthirdword
>   fourthwordfifthword|sixthword|

What I need to do is remove all text outside of the two "|" and keep the text inside of the two "|"

And then insert a Unicode zero-width-space between each of the words (U+200B)

Resulting in:

> firstwordU+200BsecondwordU+200BthirdwordU+200BfourthwordU+200BfifthwordU+200Bsixthword

I tried

```
sed '\|/d;/|/,$d' input.txt
```

UPDATE: Which doesn't do much

And

```
sed -e 's/.*|\([^]]*\)|.*/\1/g' input.txt
```

Which comes close, but doesn't remove anything from lines that do not contain a "|" (I need to remove everything not contained inside two "|"  And I don't know how to go about adding the zero-width-space between words. But like I said, I don't really know what I am doing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

-Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with the results of

```
sed -e 's/.*|\([^]]*\)|.*/\1/g' input.txt
```

other than its failure to remove lines that do not contain the delimiters, then just do:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*|\([^]]*\)|.*/\1/gp' input.txt
```

to only print lines in which the replace happens.  Or, you can explicitly delete the unwanted lines:

```
sed -e '/|.*|/!d' -e 's/.*|\([^]]*\)|.*/\1/g'
```

Comment: Great - thanks!  Do you know if it would be possible to put all the results on one line like in my example result?  I was able to add the Unicode character just by typing it in before the "\1"

Comment: I would very much hesitate to use sed for unicode.  Perhaps perl would be more appropriate.

Comment: Have you found it to be unreliable with Unicode?  I ended up pasting everything into Notepad ++ (in Windows, I am more familiar with it), and removed all the line breaks there - it seems like everything turned out...but perhaps I should explore perl.  Do you have a good place to go for examples of doing this sort of thing with perl?