# Regular expression to check if brackets are nested

Tags: linux, perl, sed

I have a large number of files which contain lines with matched braces. I do *not* care if the brackets are matched or not.

I'd like to check if any braces are nested, by checking which comes first after an opening bracket - a closing or another opening bracket. I assume that all brackets are matched, and that there is at most one outer-bracket per line. (Ie, `[foo[bar]]` is a valid line, `[foo][bar]` is not, because the second bracket pair isn't nested).

I can get everything inside a bracket pair from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905180/how-to-find-text-within-in-sed) using `'s/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'`, but I'm unsure how to re-test the grabbed string for further matches.

For example, given the following string:

```
foo [ bar, [baz] ]
```

the steps I think I would take are:

1. Traverse from the left-hand side until I see an opening bracket. (If none is found, ignore the line).
2. Non-greedily search from the opening brace until either `[` or `]` is encountered. If `[`,  brackets are nested, so return the line. If `]`,

Ideally I'd like a `sed` or unix-tool based solution, but others are acceptable (`perl`, for example). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you care about the level of nested brackets or simply ignore if such nested bracket exist?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I only care about the line if there's at least one nested bracket - I dont care about the level of nesting brackets at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print if /\[[^\]]*\[/' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
foo [ bar, [baz] ]
foo [ bar, baz ]
foo [ bar ]
foo [ bar, baz] ]
foo  bar, [baz] ]
> perl -ne 'print if /\[.*\[/' temp
foo [ bar, [baz] ]
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the recursive regexp to check brackets match AND they are nested. Its no point to check nesting without syntax check cus this can break out checking result. For example:

```
my $regex = qr/\[([^\[\]]+?|(??{$regex}))*\]/;
if( $line =~ /^[^\[\]]*\[$regex\][^\[\]]*$/ ) #Valid
```

[image: Recursive regexp]